# Concat column MYSQL

Tags: mysql, concatenation, group-concat

I Have this select

```
SELECT page.*, page_lang.*, category.title as category FROM page
JOIN page_lang ON page.id = page_lang.id_page
JOIN relation ON page.id = relation.from_id
JOIN page_lang as category ON category.id_page = relation.to_id
WHERE page.type = 'blog-detail'
AND relation.type = 1
```

This return duplicate rows when one page have two or more categories

ID PAGE | TITLE | CATEGORIES

1       | Title 1 | category 1

2       | Title 2 | category 1

3       | Title 3 | category 2

1       | Title 1 | category 2

But I want this

ID PAGE | TITLE | CATEGORIES

1       | Title 1 | category 1, category 2

2       | Title 2 | category 1

3       | Title 3 | category 2

If I use GROUP_CONCAT(category.title) return 1 row.

Comment: What is the name of the `TITLE` column in `page` table?  I doubt that the query you showed us actually generates the output given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use group_concat:

```
SELECT page.*, page_lang.*, group_concat(distinct category.title) as category FROM page
JOIN page_lang ON page.id = page_lang.id_page
JOIN relation ON page.id = relation.from_id
JOIN page_lang as category ON category.id_page = relation.to_id
WHERE page.type = 'blog-detail'
AND relation.type = 1
GROUP BY page.id
```

Comment: Thanks! It's Works!

Answer (score 0):

try using the command "UNIQUE"

```
SELECT UNIQUE page.*, page_lang.*, category.title as category FROM page
JOIN page_lang ON page.id = page_lang.id_page
JOIN relation ON page.id = relation.from_id
JOIN page_lang as category ON category.id_page = relation.to_id
WHERE page.type = 'blog-detail'
AND relation.type = 1
```

Comment: This won't give the desired output.